# Altering same column in multiple .csv files in R

Tags: r

I have a number of .csv files which are called "1_a.csv", "2_a.csv", "3_a.csv", "4_a.csv", and so on. Within each .csv file is a column called "participant", which currently has the participant number. For example, in "1_a.csv" under "participant" is 1, in "2_a.csv" under "participant" is 2.

What I would like to do is edit the column "participant" in each of these .csv files so that it also has the "_a", so in "1_a.csv" under "participant" is 1_a, in "2_a.csv" under "participant" is 2_a, and so on. However, I haven't been able to figure this out.

```
files <- list.files(path = 'data/', pattern = '*.csv', full.names = TRUE) # load data 

for (filename in files) {
  
  df = read.csv(filename)
  
  df$participant = df$participant + "_a"

}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `files`, read the data, do the `transform`ation and store in a `list`.  The `+` in `R` doesn't concatenate strings - use `paste` for that

```
lst1 <- lapply(files, function(x) {
       x1 <- transform(read.csv(x), 
     participant = paste0(participant, "_a"))
   write.csv(x1, file = x, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
   x1
})
```

---

In a `for` loop, the OP created a temporary object 'df', which gets updated in each iteration.  Instead, we may need to store it in a `list`

```
lst1 <- vector('list', length(files))
names(lst1) <- files
for (filename in files) {
  
  df = read.csv(filename)
  
  df$participant = paste0(df$participant, "_a")
  lst1[[filename]] <- df 
  write.csv(df, file = filename, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

}
```

Comment: Dear Arun is `transform` an equivalent of `mutate` in base R?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR yes, you are right.  It is similar but not equivalent as `mutate` can also refer to an object created before, but transform doesn't recognize i.e.  suppose if you need to add a new column based on participant `transform(read.csv(x), 
     participant2 = paste0(participant, "_a"), new = substr(participant2, 1, 2))` it wouldn't recognize the one created on the fly

Comment: Thank you very much, yes that's true. I need to work on base R a bit more :) Oh I understand. That's really cool.

Comment: Hi @akrun thanks for the response, this does create a list, but is there any way to then save these new dfs over the original .csv files? I tried to add something along the lines of "function(x){write.csv(df_list[[x]])" but it is still producing an error

Comment: @abc_95 you can call the `write.csv` after the transformation in the same list itself.  I updaed for both for loop and lapply